# puede un programa en c acceder con un puntero a la variable de otro programa en c

Tags: c, punteros

Estoy intentando que un programa en c lea una variable de otro programa en c pasandole su direccion de memoria pero el problema al intentar hacerlo no me deja y en vez de enseñarme el valor de la variable me enseña la direccion de memoria.

```
int main(int argc,char* argumentos[])
{
int *puntero=6356732;
printf("%d\n",*puntero);
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

si en la direccion de memoria pongo la direccion de una variable del mismo programa si que ensña el valor de la variable.

Comment: @Trauma muchas gracias 

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Por ponerlo como respuesta...

Tal como indica @Trauma, cualquier SO moderno separa la memoria de los distintos procesos. Ya no es que no permita acceder a la memoria de otros procesos, sino que cada proceso tiene un espacio de memoria separado (así que la posición de memoria 5 del proceso A no apunta a los mismos bytes "físicos" que la posición de memoria 5 del proceso B).

La solución es que los procesos deben explícitamente solicitar que el SO les asigne una zona de memoria compartida. Este proceso es bastante diferente entre SO, especialmente entre Linux/Unix(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5656530/how-to-use-shared-memory-with-linux-in-c) y Windows(https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/memory/creating-named-shared-memory).

Si el volumen de transferencia de datos no es muy grande, una opción puede ser usar comunicación entre procesos (que también es bastante dependiente de SO) o usar valores comunes en otros sistemas (p.ej., modificando una BD o ficheros en un directorio común)

Comment: tengo una duda  tengo entendido que en general las variables se guardan en la memoria ram. La memoria compartida tambien usa la ram? esque estoy mirando las paginas que habeis mandado y no me queda muy claro.

Comment: El SO muestra "memoria", y la gestiona. El proceso ve el puntero, el SO hace el resto. El proceso siempre  trabaja con la RAM, pero las direcciones que maneja son virtuales. El SO traduce las posiciones que ve el proceso a las posiciones de la RAM, y también va moviendo trozos de RAM desde y hacia disco según se usen o no.